# How to overwrite protected files in dired

Tags: dired, tramp, sudo, overwrite, emacs28

I was trying to copy my some of my config folders to another system which was mounted with root privileges using dired. I opened both surrounding folders using `/sudo::/...` and tried to copy my files from one to the other, putting again the `tramp`-sudo-prefix into the copy path and was asked whether to overwrite the target folder, but when I said yes, it still told me copying failed because the folders already existed. I also tried using the `dired-toggle-sudo`-package, but it didn't work either. If I delete the folders to be overwritten before, I can copy the folders to the destination, but this is quite cumbersome. Is there a way I can overwrite the files without having to delete them first?

Here is an example of the output:

```
Overwrite ‘/sudo:root@alex:/run/media/alex/0c989fa2-cf7a-4238-b66d-4505fbac04f7/home/alex/Documents’? [Type ynlq! or C-h] y
File already exists: /sudo:root@alex:/run/media/alex/0c989fa2-cf7a-4238-b66d-4505fbac04f7/home/alex/Documents
Copy: ‘/sudo:root@alex:/home/alex/Documents’ to ‘/sudo:root@alex:/run/media/alex/0c989fa2-cf7a-4238-b66d-4505fbac04f7/home/alex/’ failed:
(file-already-exists /sudo:root@alex:/run/media/alex/0c989fa2-cf7a-4238-b66d-4505fbac04f7/home/alex/Documents)
```

I'm using Emacs 28.2 and Tramp 2.5.3.28.2.

Comment: Could you give an example? There are subtle differences in overwriting files, depending on whether the target is a directory or not, and whether the target has a trailing slash when it is a directory. Pls show also the Emacs and Tramp versions you use.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus I added example output and version information to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem with Emacs 28.3 / Tramp 2.5.4-pre. Running the very same recipe with Emacs 29.0.90 / Tramp 2.6.0.29.1 works as expected.

Emacs 29.1 is in pretest. So I recommend for the time being to install Tramp 2.6.0.4 from GNU ELPA.